# How to write pymongo query to get all the data based on date time Python

Tags: python, pymongo

I have more than 100 documents in `mongodb` which has below data:

```
{
    "Length": 2.9,
    "Number": 33,
    "Stop Time": "2020-09-20T11:05:58",
    "Start Time": "2020-09-20T11:05:53"
}
```

I want a query to get all the documents which has `Start Time` greater than lets say `2020-09-20T11:00:00` and less than `"Stop Time": "2020-09-21T11:10:00"`

For this I have written below query

```
query = [{'$match': {'Start Time': {'$gte': '2020-09-20T11:00:00'}, 'Stop Time': {'$lt': '2020-09-21T11:10:00'}}}]
```

So I want to get all the documents between the datetime `2020-09-20T11:00:00` till `2020-09-21T11:10:00`.

In mongodb I have manually check and I have 56 documents present for above date time range but running this query, I am only able to get for `2020-09-20` and there is not data present for `2020-09-21`. Is there anything missing in my query

```
data_list = []
document = opc_collection.aggregate(query)
for x in document:
    data_list.append(x)
print(data_list)
```

EDIT:

Below is the data after converting from string to date time in db:

```
{
    "Length": 2.9,
    "Number": 33,
    "Stop Time": "2020-09-20 11:05:58",
    "Start Time": "2020-09-20 11:05:53"
}

query = [{'$match': {'Start Time': {'$gte': '2020-09-20 11:00:00'}, 'Stop Time': {'$lt': '2020-09-21 11:10:00'}}}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your date `2020-09-20T11:00:00` is of type string. You have to convert it to a datetime.

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("2020-09-20T11:00:00", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: The datetime stored in mongodb is also in string and If that was the case, I wouldn't have got the data for `2020-09-20`. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Oh ok. Is it possible for you to change the type in database and store dates instead? Because pymongo will compare string by the alphabetical order and will not compare them as dates. It is however possible of changing the type of the field in a mongo query, but it will be slower than directly comparing dates.

Comment: I just did quick test by saving the date time instead of string. First of all, I don't know why current time is `20:52` but mongodb is saving it as `02:23`. I have applied the above query but still not getting any results

Comment: The time difference is maybe due to time zone. Mongo store a parameter at the end of the date like in `2020-09-21T12:08:46.512890+02:00`. So you have `ISODate(...)` in db and when you are querying you have converted your string to a datetime object ?

Comment: So when I am querying I have to query based on current time or the time zone its saved in db?

Comment: mongo we will do the conversion. If you pass a date without a timezone, it will be considered to be GMT by default.

Comment: Can you update the question with the changes you've done on your query and on the data in database ?

Comment: Updated the questions

Comment: It seems that you still don't have date format even if even the string format have changed

Comment: No. I think my query was wrong. If we want to get data based on `gte` and `lte` we need to have one attribute to search. For ex: `query = [{'$match': {'Start Time': {'$gte': '2020-09-20 11:00:00', '$lte': '2020-09-21 11:10:00'}}}]`, this gives me all the data. I still unable to understand how can we use `gte` and `lte` on two different attributes i.e. `Start Time` and `Stop Time`

Comment: Your query work well, you can try it here : https://mongoplayground.net/p/IupJ3NBTPEg